# How to target object property within nested array and set the conditional?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using the following array data how can I specifically target *price* to set the conditional if the value matches *20239* to replace the value with something else?

```
[
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ],
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ],
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ] 
]
```

Comment: The question is not clear. You can explore array filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just traverse the array.

Its array of arrays of objects, so you need to go through every "upper" array to get "inner" array. Inside that inner array you have to go through all items, which are objects. For each object you can check the price or other things and change it as you like it.

```js
const arrs = [
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ],
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ],
  [ 
    { quantity: 3, price: 30000 },
    { quantity: 3, price: 20239 } 
  ] 
]

arrs.forEach(arr => arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.price === 20239) {
    obj.price = 42
  }
}))

console.log(arrs)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation as well. Helps a lot and I really appreciate it!